# Something is wrong with my multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2cm}}
\hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Latin America}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Africa}\\
\hline
  & {\large $\Delta p_c$} &  {\large $\Delta p_o$} & {\large $\Delta p_c$} & {\large $\Delta p_o$}\\
\hline
{\large $\Delta p_{c-1}$} &–1.191***    & 0.361*** & –1.07*** & 0.382** \\
  & (0.153) & (0.153) & (0.16) & (0.196) \\

{\large$\Delta p_{o-1}$} & –0.084 & –0.084 & 0.120 & 0.283*\\  
& (0.149) & (0.149) &(0.215) & (0.155)\\  

$c$ & –0.001 & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.003\\  
& (0.025) & (0.025) & (0.029) & (0.035)\\  

$\alpha $& 0.073 & –0.580*** & 0.150 & –0.497***\\  
& (0.323) & (0.172) & (0.236) & (0.197)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}| p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm}}
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Test results}\\
\hline

$R^2$ &0.428 &  & 0.174 & & 0.428 & & 0.174 \\

\textit{F-statistic} & 6.988** &  & 3.181* &  & 6.988** & & 3.181*\\  

\textit{Log Likelihood} &  & 30.87 &  &  &  & 16.57 &\\  

\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{LM-Test (p-values) for autocorrelation, lag 1}} & & & & & & &\\  
& (0.323) & (0.172) & (0.236) & (0.197) & \\
& (0.025) & (0.025) & (0.029) & (0.035) &\\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Please help me figure this out... the last row just isn't working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I will work on your table to make it clearer, it'll just take some time :)

Answer (score 9):

Here you go. I suppose that this was the intention of the table. I changed the layout completely since I didn't find out the original table quite visually appealing. I hope you'll like it.

[image]

Some comments:

- It looks like one table, not like two, so I made it one table.
- Please do not use `\large` inappropriately, there's no need for it in a table.
- `\multirow` is over-estimated, I consider it useless.
- Note the usage of `\cmidrule(lr)` to separate the two pairs of columns.
- In order to nicely align the number by the decimal point, I used `r@{.}l` column construct and replaced all `.` by `&`. I would have used `S[table-format=0.3]` column from `siunitx`, but it doesn't support parenthesized numbers out-of-the-box.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\providecommand\Midrule{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{>$r<$@{.}>$l<$}}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Latin America}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Africa}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta p_c$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta p_o$}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta p_c$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta p_o$}\\
\Midrule
    $\Delta p_{c-1}$ &-1&191^{***}    & 0&361^{***} & -1&07^{***} & 0&382^{**} \\
        & (0&153) & (0&153) & (0&16) & (0&196) \\
\midrule
    $\Delta p_{o-1}$ & -0&084 & -0&084 & 0&120 & 0&283^{*}\\  
        & (0&149) & (0&149) &(0&215) & (0&155)\\  
\midrule
    $c$ & -0&001 & 0&005 & 0&001 & 0&003\\  
        & (0&025) & (0&025) & (0&029) & (0&035)\\  
\midrule
    $\alpha $& 0&073 & -0&580^{***} & 0&150 & -0&497^{***}\\  
        & (0&323) & (0&172) & (0&236) & (0&197)\\
\Midrule
    \multicolumn{9}{c}{\bfseries Test results}\\
\Midrule
    $R^2$ &0&428 & 0&174 & 0&428 & 0&174 \\
\midrule
    $F$-statistic & 6&988^{**} &  3&181^{*} &  6&988^{**} & 3&181^{*}\\  
\midrule
    $\log$ likelihood & \multicolumn{4}{c}{30.87} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{16.57}\\  
\midrule
    LM-Test ($p$-values) for
        & (0&323) & (0&172) & (0&236) & (0&197) \\
    autocorrelation, lag 1
        & (0&025) & (0&025) & (0&029) & (0&035) \\  
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost like @tohecz, but with the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\providecommand\Midrule{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post =\textsuperscript{***}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{S[}}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Latin America}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Africa}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    & {$\Delta p_c$} & {$\Delta p_o$} &{$\Delta p_c$} & {$\Delta p_o$}\\
\Midrule
    $\Delta p_{c-1}$ &-1.191\textsuperscript{***} & 0.361\textsuperscript{***} & -1.07\textsuperscript{\hskip -0.5em{***}} & 0.382\textsuperscript{**} \\
        & {(}0.153{)} &{(}0.153{)} & {(}0.16{\hskip -0.5em)} &{(}0.196{)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    $\Delta p_{o-1}$ & -0.084 & -0.084 & 0.120 & 0.283\textsuperscript{*}\\
        & {(}0.149{)} & {(}0.149{)} &{(}0.215{)} & {(}0.155{)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    $c$ & -0.001 & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.003\\
        & {(}0.025{)} & {(}0.025{)} & {(}0.029{)} & {(}0.035{)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    $\alpha $& 0.073 & -0.580\textsuperscript{***} & 0.150 & -0.497\textsuperscript{***}\\
        & {(}0.323{)} & {(}0.172{)} & {(}0.236{)} & {(}0.197{)}\\
\Midrule
\addlinespace[3ex]
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\bfseries Test results}\\
\Midrule
    $R^2$ &0.428 & 0.174 & 0.428 & 0.174 \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    $F$-statistic & 6.988\textsuperscript{**} & 3.181\textsuperscript{*} & 6.988\textsuperscript{**} & 3.181\textsuperscript{*}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    $\log$ likelihood & \multicolumn{2}{c}{30.87} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{16.57}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-5}
    LM-Test ($p$-values) for
        & {(}0.323{)} & {(}0.172{)} & {(}0.236{)} & {(}0.197{)} \\
    autocorrelation, lag 1
        & {(}0.025{)} & {(}0.025{)} & {(}0.029{)} & {(}0.035{)} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]